# Show that every planar graph admits an orientation such that each vertex has at most five outgoing edges

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

An orientation of any graph $G = (V, E)$ is defined as any graph $G' = (V, E')$ arising by replacing each edge $\{u, v\}$ of $E(G)$ by a directed edge either  $\{u, v\}$ or $\{v, u\}$. Show that every planar graph admits an orientation such that each vertex has at most five outgoing edges.

Intuitively I can see this to be true but I am having a hard time producing a formal proof for this. I was thinking of a case distinction where I can split the cases 1) the degree of any vertex of G is at most 5 (this case is trivially true) and 2) there exist vertices of degree more than 5 (having a lot of trouble trying to prove this). I'd really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 5):

Let $n$ be the number of vertices.

Proceed by induction on $n$.

For $n=1$, the result is trivially true.

Thus, suppose a planar graph $G$ has $n$ vertices, with $n \ge 2$.

But every planar graph has some vertex $v$ of degree at most $5$.

For a proof, see Theorem 5.8.6 (page 182), and Lemma 5.8.15 (page 184) of this MIT OCW textbook:

> https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-042j-mathematics-for-computer-science-fall-2010/readings/MIT6_042JF10_notes.pdf

Hence by the inductive hypothesis, $G-v$ can be oriented as specified.

To complete the orientation on $G$, just orient the edges from $v$ as outgoing.

Comment: Are you sure that this is a complete proof? Seems rather simple for a such a proof. I am well familiar with this theorem "every planar graph has some vertex vv of degree at most 5" but I don't see how it completes the inductive step and the proof

Comment: @Abby: When you remove $v$, the resulting graph, $G−v$, is still planar, and has $n−1$ vertices, so by the inductive hypothesis, there is some qualifying orientation on $G−v$. The oriented $G−v$ has all the vertices of $G$ except $v$, and all the edges of $G$ except the edges incident with $v$. If we orient the edges incident with $v$ as outgoing, then $v$ has at most $5$ outgoing edges, and the number of outgoing edges for the vertices other than $v$ remains the same.

Comment: Note that one advantage of the inductive proof is that it's _constructive_. It shows you how to actually _make_ a qualifying orientation.

Comment: oh yeah, it makes sense. btw, what would be the Induction Hypothesis in this case?

Comment: The induction hypothesis is that the claim is true for any planar graph with $n-1$ points.

Comment: why n-1? shouldn't we assume it for n and then remove the vertex so that we are left with n-1 vertices on which we perform the inductive step?

Comment: We're trying to prove the truth for $P(n)$, so you certainly can't assume $P(n)$ is true. Instead, we show the assumed truth of $P(n-1)$ implies the truth of $P(n)$. Perhaps you're more used to seeing induction as $P(n)$ implies $P(n+1)$, but $P(n-1)$ implies $P(n)$ is the same thing.

Comment: I am not confused by $P(n-1)$ $ ->$  $P(n)$. I am a little confused right now :D how do we show that the last vertex added is the one with degree at most 5?

Comment: We _chose_ that vertex. It wasn't a random choice. But by the inductive hypothesis, we know that _any_ planar graph with $n-1$ vertices is orientable as specified, so we can remove any $v$ we want. And the $v$ we want, in order to make the induction work, is a vertex with degree at most $5$.

Comment: alright thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Do you know the relatively easy proof of the six-colour and five-colour theorems for planar graphs? You can mirror the strategy for those as follows:

1. Show that any planar graph has at least one vertex of degree at most five
2. Consider a minimal counterexample. Deduct a vertex of degree at most five. Solve the smaller graph, and add the deleted vertex back in an appropriate way.
3. Show that a graph with only one vertex and no edges has the relevant property (so the set of solvable graphs is not empty)

Comment: +1 for minimal counterexample rather than induction (this is just personal preference)

Comment: yeah, I don't like induction either. would you perhaps expand on this a bit further? at step 2 I mean

Comment: @Abby It is essentially the same as the induction step in the induction proof. If you take away a point with five or fewer edges, you can make an arrangement for the rest by minimality. Add the vertex back and direct the five or fewer added edges away from the added vertex. This satisfies the condition.

Comment: oh great. in any case, although I personally hate Induction, I am gonna use that stick with that proof instead cause it's easier to understand/

Comment: @Abby You should find the proofs of the $6,5-$ colour theorems and the strategy employed for the four colour theorem. The minimal counterexample approach is often equivalent to induction, but can make for much easier explanation, particularly where the case for $n$ can be extended in many different ways to the case for $n+1$ and it is difficult to control the rate of growth. Going down then simplifies the problem.